# Как получить данные переменных php через ajax

Tags: php, ajax

// PHP файл data.php

```
if (isset($_POST['win'])) {
$stat = $LS->getUser('win');
$many = $LS->getUser('many');

if ($stat == 3) {
    $kof = 3;
}else{
    $kof = 1.9;
}
$sum = $LS->getUser('many') + (int)($_POST['win'] * $kof);
$x = $LS->updateUser(array("many" => $sum)); 
}
```

// файл index.php

```
$.ajax ({
    url: "engine/data.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: ("win"),
    success: 
});
```

Помогите вытащить переменные $many и $kof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно использовать `json_encode()`

```
if(isset($_POST['win'])) {
    $many = '...';
    $kof = '...';

    echo json_encode(array($many, $kof));
}

$.get('engine/data.php', function(data) {
    alert('Data Loaded: ' + data);
});
```

[json_encode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php)

[jQuery.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)